# Only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index

Tags: python, nlp, tensor

```
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2')

train_data_path = 'train_dataset.txt'

with open(train_data_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
train_text = file.read()

train_encodings = tokenizer(train_text, return_tensors='pt', truncation=True, max_length=128)

train_dataset = TextDataset(
tokenizer=tokenizer,
file_path=train_encodings\['input_ids'\],
block_size=128,
)

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=4, shuffle=True)

optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=5e-5)

for epoch in range(3):  # Adjust the number of epochs as needed
for batch in train_loader:
inputs = batch\["input_ids"\]
labels = batch\["labels"\]
outputs = model(inputs, labels=labels)
loss = outputs.loss
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
optimizer.zero_grad()

model.save_pretrained('D:/Data Science/2. Notebooks/')
tokenizer.save_pretrained('D:/Data Science/2. Notebooks/')
```

---

The error happens here

```
train_dataset = TextDataset(tokenizer=tokenizer, file_path=train_encodings['input_ids'], block_size=128,)       train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=4, shuffle=True)
```

---

The error is:

```
TypeError: only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index
```

---

train_encodings:

```
{'input_ids': tensor([[   42,    72, 16175,  1134, 10662,  1878,    80,  1031,   264, 30102,            430, 12379, 33133, 21681, 30102,    77,   324,   133,   247,    74,            334, 15201, 30102,    81,   198,  2202, 21681, 30102,    77,   331,            263,   521,   133,   247, 28808,    72,   819,    75,   133,   247,             81,   256,  1134,   346,    76,   133,   247,    75,   312,   343,            198,   128,   108,   358,    72,   277,  1134, 12769,   299,   133,            247, 15908,   390,    88, 17062,   133,   247,    77,   198,    48,          30102,    89, 30102,    75,   479, 25236,   264,   361,   133,   247,          28781,   133,   247,    81,   220,   133,   247, 18809,   133,   247,           1225,   133,   247,    81,   133,   247,    74, 28808,    72,   512,          21681,   331, 34174,    76, 30102, 46481, 21681,   198, 34458, 46481,          20402,   465,    82,   133,   247,    75,   133,   247,  4372,   133,            247,  1312, 46481,    75,   133,   247,    81,   308]]), 'attention_mask': tensor([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])}
```

How can I solve this issue?

I tried converting to the numpy array, but it causes an error too